# How are sudo permissions granted across parent/children processes?

Tags: linux, permissions, sudo, subshell

I was having a look at how sudo grants work across parent/children processes, however, I'm confused.

If I open a terminal (emulator, in a graphic environment), and execute:

```bsh
$ sudo bash -c "sudo -v"
# I'm asked the password
$ sudo -v
# I'm not asked the password
```

I can see that if a child process is granted sudo permissions (through a subshell), the parent (the current shell) is granted them as well.

However, if I open a new tab in the same terminal emulator, and execute:

```bsh
$ sudo -v
```

now I'm asked the password.

Since both shells/tabs are children of the same terminal emulator process, then the sudo grants are based on something different/additional compared to the simple parent/child relationship.

I've checked the sudo man page, however, it seems it doesn't contain this specific information.

How are permissions precisely granted, in relation to parent/child processes?

Comment: As @roaima wrote : the credential cache can be used and not. 'sudo -K' will remove the time stamp, but the time stamp isnt assigned to the terminal emulator process, it is assigned to it's child, the bash process.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I can see that if a child process is granted sudo permissions (through a subshell), the parent (the current shell) is granted them as well.

No. The child doesn't affect the parent.

The second `sudo` requires no password because you run it less than 5 minutes after the first one.

The `sudo` in the other window runs in a different shell, which has a different credentials cache then the shell in the first window. The cache is empty, therefore a password is required.

Comment: "...which _usually_ has a different credentials cache...". For example I have my personal systems set to authenticate regardless of terminal device

Comment: I see. So, it's correct to say that the sudo permissions are cached across a shell tree (ie. parent shell/children shells)?

Comment: @Marcus NO. The permissions are not cached. The authentication is cached. No permission flows to the parent. But the parent can grant permission (with `sudo`), until the authentication expires.